# Transform a Matrix into an Edge List in EXCEL

Tags: excel

I have an excel matrix that looks like this:

```
ID   A B C D E F G 
XYZ  0 1 0 1 0 1 0
ZVC  1 0 1 0 1 0 1
...
ABC  0 1 0 1 0 1 1
```

I would like to transform this matrix into three columns:

```
XYZ A 0
XYZ B 1
XYZ C 0
...
ABC F 1
ABC G 1
```

What would be an efficient way to do that (possibly without macros)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a simple solution to my problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3wWQjRWkJc